# Reverse engineering old mmo

Tags: ida, c++

I am newish to reverse engineering and have a question about a problem with IDA Pro. I am trying to reverse engineer an old mmo game. Anyone know why dword_ calls show as "dd ?"? Float numbers and plain text shows up in the .rdata section except for dwords. Is this of any importance in reverse engineering said application?[image]